# Howto cache images on IIS7

Tags: caching, iis-7, amazon-s3, image-caching

I have a web application that get a big amount of images via a server script proxy
which re-sizes them to specific thumbnails size.
so the url of a given image would be something like:
myDomain.com/scripts/myScript.php?url=anotherDomain.com/images/someImage.jpg&width=120&height=80

Due to some requirements I have to proxy these images this way, and I need to cache these images to ease the load on the server processing and re-sizing.

How do I go about configuring IIS7 to cache these urls?
I don't have in-depth knowledge of headers, so if needed, your elaboration will be very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Alternatively, we can run a process to re-size all images in the DB and store those on S3. any straight forward pointers to caching images via s3?

Answer (score 0):

click your site, click http Response headers, then click "set common headers", then expire web content and uncheck "immediately", then specify when you'd like it to expire.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28v=ws.10%29.aspx/)